# How to handle properly two arguments for one option in python script command line?

Tags: python

I have a "main.py" python script. I want to handle two arguments for one option when I run my script in command line.

For example, I will write the following command in my terminal:

```
python main.py --interval 2 4
```

I want to be able to get these 2 arguments (2 and 4) for this specific option (--interval) in my program.

"main.py" program:

```
from sys import argv
from getopt import getopt, GetoptError


try:
    opts, args = getopt(argv[1:], "i:", ["interval="])
except GetoptError:
    print("usage: main.py --interval <start value> <end value>")
    exit(2)

for opt, arg in opts:
    if opt in ("-i", "--interval"):
        print("Start value: " + arg + ", end value: " + "?")
```

You can see in the last line of the program, I put a question mark at the place I would get the second argument for the "--interval" option.

The result I want should be:

```
Start value: 2, end value: 4
```

I know for this simple example I could just use argv[1] for the option, argv[2] and argv[3] for the arguments. But I would like to know if it is possible to do it with "getopt" library and if yes, if it is the proper way to do it.

Comment: Have you considered using `argparse`? *"Users who are unfamiliar with the C `getopt()` function or who would like to write less code and get better help and error messages should consider using the [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) module instead."*

Comment: Thanks to this thread, I'm definitely going to take a long look at argparse.   However, if you are devoted to using getopt, you should know that an option takes at most one argument.    So, you could _cheat_ if you really wanted to move on quickly ( read that as, you don't care about quality ) .  The cheat in this case is passing the interval as a space delimited string.   This is tough on operators, but they could run your program as: `program.py --interval="2 4"`.  Of course, your code would have to split the option.  You would also need to have suitable documentation.

Comment: @Mark, I generally use argparse pretty successfully for parsing this stuff so I haven't tried anything else. However, I've heard good things about [click](http://click.pocoo.org/5/), and Google recently open sourced [python-fire](https://github.com/google/python-fire). You might want to try them if `argparse` doesn't scratch your itch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module in the standard library has an example just like this:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
                    help='an integer for the accumulator')
parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
                    const=sum, default=max,
                    help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.accumulate(args.integers))
```

In your example, you can simply replace the `nargs='+'` argument with `nargs=2`. Doing that produces the following usage message on my terminal (pass the `-h` flag to get usage):

```
usage: tmp.py [-h] [--sum] N N
```